# Swift - auto order UITableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a `UITableView` which is basically a To-Do-List. Is there a way to "auto-reorder" the list so the "checked" `cells` are automatically going to do the bottom of the list so the "unchecked" items stay on top?

I hope you understand why my problem is.. Just ask if anything is unclear. I couldn't find anything to that topic so I am grateful for every help! :)

This is my `UITableView`:

```
    import UIKit

class WhishlistTableViewController: UITableViewController {

    public var wishList = [Wish]()


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // disable prefill tableview with cells
        let v = UIView()
        v.backgroundColor = .clear
        tableView.tableFooterView = v

        // disable didSelectAt
        self.tableView.allowsSelection = false

        self.tableView.register(WhishCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: WhishCell.reuseID)
        self.wishList.append(Wish(withWishName: "Test"))

        // add top inset for tavleview
        self.tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 10, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)


    }

    // MARK: - Table view data source
    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return wishList.count
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: WhishCell.reuseID, for: indexPath) as! WhishCell
        let currentWish = self.wishList[indexPath.row]
        cell.label.text = currentWish.wishName
        cell.backgroundColor = .clear




        return cell
    }

}

class Wish: NSObject {
    public var wishName : String?
    init(withWishName name: String) {
        super.init()
        wishName = name
    }
}
```

Comment: yes, you can create a new array that has a flag: true or false, and you can sort the new array and reloadData, show me your code and I will help you

Comment: alright on sec :)

Comment: just edited my post

Comment: Unrelated but never declare a property as optional (`wishName`) which is initialized with a non-optional value.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do this every edit of any item inside the array

```
wishList.partition(by: { $0.checked }) // it's mutating and ignore the return
```

i suppose that you have `checked` bool property inside your `Wish` model

Comment: could you elaborate on this? I am not quite sure what you mean

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a Wish class with a name var and a selected boolean var.
2. Create your list of item of type Wish (You already done this step).
3. On table view selection (didSelectRow function):

3.1. Get the selected Wish from the list of items.

3.2. Set the Wish as selected (or deselected).

3.3. Reorder your list of item:

```
wishList.sorted(by: { !$0.selected })
```

3.4 Reload your table view data.

Comment: I actually use a `UIButton` inside my `cell`  to "check" it. So I don't use `didSelectRow` at all.

Comment: Ohhh, that's not a good approach, if you follow iOS ideas this is a simple/basic problem.

Comment: it is doing exactly what I need it to do. Is you solution not transferable to my case?

Comment: It's just a recommendation: follow the principles of iOS development and you are not going to have this kind of problems.

Comment: I really don't see why having a `Button` inside my `cell` is against iOS principles, but I am very new to this so happy for every help :)

Comment: It's just a best way to resolve the same problem, but my recommendation is that you should use the didSelectRow delegate function and not to use a button.

Answer (score 0):

When ever the data change occurred. `didSet` Will called. Tableview will   reload instantly.

```swift
var wishList: [Wish] = [] {
        didSet {
            wishList.sorted(by: { !$0.selected })
             tableview.reloadData()
        }
    }
```

Comment: this throws this error: `Contextual closure type '(Wish, Wish) throws -> Bool' expects 2 arguments, but 1 was used in closure body`

Answer (score -1):

check this code, and tell me if I fail, you need touch cell for check the task

```
import UIKit

class Wish: NSObject {
public var wishName : String?
public var flag : Bool?

init(withWishName name: String, flagStatus: Bool) {
    super.init()
    flag = flagStatus
    wishName = name
 }
}


class WhishlistTableViewController: UITableViewController {

public var wishList = [Wish]()


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // disable prefill tableview with cells
    let v = UIView()
    v.backgroundColor = .clear
    tableView.tableFooterView = v

    // disable didSelectAt
    self.tableView.allowsSelection = false

    self.tableView.register(WhishCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: WhishCell.reuseID)
    self.wishList.append(Wish(withWishName: "Test", flagStatus: false))

    // add top inset for tavleview
    self.tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 10, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)


}

// MARK: - Table view data source
override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return wishList.count
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: WhishCell.reuseID, for: indexPath) as! WhishCell
    let currentWish = self.wishList[indexPath.row]
    cell.label.text = currentWish.wishName
    cell.backgroundColor = .clear
    return cell
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) {
         cell.accessoryType = .Checkmark
    }
    wishList[indexPath.row].flag = true
    sortData()
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
   if let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) {
    cell.accessoryType = .None
   }
   wishList[indexPath.row].flag = false
   sortData()
}
func sortData()
  {
    wishList.sort { $0.flag!}
    tableView.reloadData()
  }
}
```

Comment: not working for me. Sorry I should've added that I "check" my items by the click of a `UIButton` inside my `cell` and don't use `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` for that.

Comment: what does the button do exactly? and where its declared?

Comment: the button is declared in my custom `wishCell` and it is a button that the user can "tick off"